# Perl: make a pdf not only from jpg

Tags: perl, pdf

I have the following script to make pdf from jpgs. It should be easy to modify it to create pdf from pngs and tifs. Well, in fact it is not. The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;
use strict;
use warnings;

# assume all just one directory path
my $folder = join(' ', @ARGV);

# deal with dos paths
$folder =~ s|\\|/|g;

$folder =~ s|/$||;

my $pdf_file = $folder . '.pdf';

die "Not a folder!\n" unless -d $folder;
die "There's already a pdf of that name!\n" if -f $pdf_file;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

#indepedently works OK - JPG
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.jpg" ) {
    my $jpg = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);

indepedently works OK - PNG
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.png" ) {
    my $png = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_png($png);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);

#indepedently works OK - TIF
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.tif" ) {
    my $tif = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_tiff($tif);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);
```

When I comment the JPG part, it works for PNG, when I comment JPG and PNG part, it works for TIFs. However, it fails to work for all the extensions: JPG, PNG and TIF.

Comment: No, the problem is that the regex on the previous line doesn't have a closing delimiter.

Comment: Also, JPEG files don't usually end in `.jepg`, but that's one of the things you're allowing. And, you're closing the directory after each loop, but you're still trying to read from it. Plus, missing closing braces and likely other syntax errors I didn't catch. If all the code is doing almost exactly the same thing, that's a good candidate for a subroutine.

Comment: One more thing (maybe): `close` closes a filehandle, not a directory handle. You want `closedir`.

Comment: IMO `opendir` is less useful than just using `glob` for 99% of use cases, because it expands the path as well.

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks for this. Thanks for this. `next unless $file =~ /\.je?pg$/i;` works for *.jpg and for *.jpeg. This is not an issue.

Comment: @menteith I assure you, it does not.

Comment: @Matt Jacob. Sorry, you are right. It works only for jpg and not for jpeg. I changed it to: `next unless $file =~ /\.jpeg|jpg/;` it appears that now everything is fine.

Comment: That probably doesn't match what you think either. Maybe you want: `/\.jpe?g$/`?

Comment: @Sobrique Your solution works and mine too. However, I will follow yours. Could you discuss your suggestion about using `glob` in more detail, please?

Comment: Yours will match `thisisajpg.txt`. `glob` lets you get a list of files matching a file spec. So you can do: `glob "/path/to/*.jpg"` and get a list of files, without needing to `opendir` or re-insert the path.

Comment: Great. I am looking in this right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your error tells you where the problem is:

> (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 40)

```
next unless $file =~ /\.tif$;
```

Should be

```
next unless $file =~ /\.tif$/;
```

Whilst we're at it:

- add `use warnings;`
- `opendir`/`closedir` would generally be better using `glob` instead. E.g.:

  ```
  foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.jpg" ) {

  }
  ```
- You don't actually terminate that second loop - you probably need a `}` somewhere - presumably before the `close` statement.
- You might need to `opendir` again, because you `closedir` and then try and `readdir`.

Comment: This was very helpful. I am a perl newbie, so I will takes me some time to rewrite the code. I will get back tomorrow. Now I can make a pdf file from tifs so there is an improvement.

Comment: I have written the code using `glob`. It only works for certain file extensions: when only the JPG part of code is present it works, the same is for the TIF and PNG code. I cannot make it working for all extensions: it fails after the first loop (jpgs) cannot find any jpgs in a folder.

Comment: You can specify multiple arguments to glob.

Comment: I google and I can use glob "$folder/*.{jpg,png,tif}" but function to make pdf is different to each fil extension (my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg); for pdf my $image = $pdf->image_tiff($tif); for tif etc.

Comment: I think we are straying into a different question,  best asked separately.

Comment: OK, I will ask another question.